# Is it possible to tell iphone 4 to use @2x graphics in a web page

Tags: iphone, html, css

I'm building an iOS centric web page using HTML5, CSS3 and Javascript with jQuery and jQTouch.

I've searched for the possibility of including @2x graphics so iPhone 4 can use it, but haven't found any information about this.

Is this possible or not? Anybody know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure is:

http://flowz.com/2010/07/css-image-replacement-for-iphone-4-high-dpi-retina-display/

Comment: Great post! Thanks. I love it when I learn something really valuable 3 minutes after posting a question :)